Unknown layer exception when downloading WMS chip with owslib
I'm attempting to download an image-chip from the Dutch hires imagery WMS, using owslib. The WMS URL is https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/luchtfotorgb/wms/v1_0?request=GetCapabilities&service=wms.
wms = WebMapService(r'https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/luchtfotorgb/wms/v1_0',
                    version='1.3.0')

The WMS contains several layers, I'm interested in Actueel_ortho25:
layer = 'Actueel_ortho25'
assert layer in wms.contents

My bounding box is defined in EPSG:28992 coordinates:
assert 'EPSG:28992' in wms[layer].crsOptions

The image request is formatted as (based on wmslib manual).
img = wms.getmap(
    layers=[layer],
    srs='EPGS:28992',
    bbox=(116000, 399000, 116200, 399200),
    size=(800, 800),
    format='image/jpeg',
    transparant=True
)

This gives: owslib.util.ServiceException: unknown layer: Actueel_ortho25_jpeg.
What am I missing?

That error message is very misleading. You have a typo in the srs argument - srs='EPGS:28992' i.e. EPGS instead of EPSG.
Change that to srs='EPSG:28992' and your code works.

Note that the misleading error message is returned by the service, not by owslib as you can see if you you follow the link that owslib generates - service.pdok.nl/hwh/luchtfotorgb/wms/v1_0?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=Actueel_ortho25&crs=EPGS%3A28992&etc...
